# Django templates parameters

Tags: django, templates, format

I have a problem with passing arguments to django template. I need to make every float/double value passed to template visible with specified precision, let's say I want to have a number with accuracy of two decimal places.

Is there any nice way to make it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `floatformat` template filter. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

To get accuracy of two decimal places, you would do

```
{{ value|floatformat:2 }}
```

Which would output any number to precision of two decimal places.

Comment: Thanks very much zanderle! Now I know when I need to check tags and filters of django's docs :)

Comment: You're welcome @hebius . Mark the answer as correct, if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

See built in template filters
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/

Use `floatformat` filter

```
{{ value|floatformat:2 }}
```

For `value = 3.1415` it will output `3.14`.